# Multiple Navigation Bar colours for a complex storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have 48 view controllers in my storyboard / project. I wish to have 2 different types of Navigation Bar designs.

Style 1 is a navigation bar and a status bar that is white and grey (colours not important to the question)

Style 2 is a navigation bar without a status bar. This is black.

I have set style 1 in the app delegate and set style 2 within one of the views. To a point this works and style 2 overwrites style 1. However, when I navigate away from the view, style 2 continues to override.

I could set each view controller explicitly but with 48 views and 4 or 5 lines of code to define the style is seems inefficient. If I later choose to change the style I then have 48 instances of code to edit.

My major experience is with PHP and if I had this situation I would make an include statement to reference style1 or style2 as needed.

I have tried to create a function in Swift to call the desired design but I cannot get it work as it doesn't reference the UIViewController in the same way you would when adding it directly. I have only been coding for Swift / Xcode for 3 months so it could my lack of knowledge.

I would like to find a solution that on each view I can call something like below (PseudoCode)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
navBarStyle1() or navBarStyle2()
}
```

I have not included my code to adjust the colours as I feel this is not needed for the answer.

What would be the best way to manage this efficiently? Is there an equivalent to a PHP include? If the solution is a function, could you provide an example? Or may be the solution is something different?

As requested, here is one of my view controllers:

```
import UIKit

class DeleteMatchViewController: UIViewController {


    var idPass = ""

    // OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var errorMessage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var information: UILabel!

    // ACTIONS
    @IBAction func deleteMatch(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


        // connect and delete from server
        // delete from core data
        // load from core data


        let urlParameters = "removed for privacy"
        let status = sendSeverV2("\(apiUrl)/removedforprivacy.php", parameters: urlParameters)

        if status == "OK"
        {

            // DELETESINGLE firstname|David
            myDatabase("Matches",        theCommand: "DELETESINGLE",   theQuery: "userid|\(idPass)")
            myDatabase("Messages",       theCommand: "DELETEMULTIPLE", theQuery: "people|\(userId)-\(idPass)")
            myDatabase("Messagesunsent", theCommand: "DELETEMULTIPLE", theQuery: "people|\(userId)-\(idPass)")
            // core data
            loadMatchesFromCoreData()
            // segue to matches table
            performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpMatches", sender: nil)

        }
        if status == "Error"
        {
          errorMessage.text = "Connection error"
        }


        if status == "Security"
        {
            errorMessage.text = "Authentication error"
            authError = "yes"
        }

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
        errorMessage.text = ""
        information.text = "If you delete this match all messages will be erased and only a future mutual match will all you to contact them again."


    }



}
```

Comment: A little bit of Object-Oriented design would go a long way.  Not only could your view controllers inherit setting this property, you'd probably end up with far fewer than 48 view controllers...

Comment: The purpose of this site is to help people with an answer, rather than down voting and providing a comment that is of little help. I may be new to swift coding and you may be an expert but you are far from helpful. I have many views and my app is not trivial. It's a fully featured online dating app with live chat, messages, profiles, settings, reporting, security, picture uploads, matches, display preferences and more. If you know the answer then help, if you don't, then don't comment.

Comment: I assure you, the app I am working on now is more complicated, but that is really irrelevant. Your code doesn't have to be as complicated as the app... That's the whole point of oop. If I post an answer (and I still may later today when I have some more time), you'll only post comments asking for further clarification because your app is so far from oop...

Comment: Do you have *any* view controller inheritance in your app?

Comment: I don't intent to rework what I have. I just want to know the best solution for the position I have right now. If that means I have to add the code on every view then so be it, but if there is a away to include a section of code from a single source that would be very helpful to me, or call a function that can set the nav bar style. My work may not be perfect (internally) but the result is fast, great UI and very stable. RE: Inheritance. ?? Each view has it's own source.

Comment: Do you know what OOP is? Are you familiar with inheritance? These comments I'm leaving are crucially relevant to the amount of "Tell me like I'm five" any answer needs to be.

Comment: I'm new to Swift and my code style is more procedural as that's my experience.

Comment: Then you are in desperate need of some object-oriented education. It's not a style choice... It is basically required in order to build a decent ***and maintainable*** iOS application.

Comment: Can you post *one* of your view controllers? Or better yet, post *two* that have a lot in common. (We both know there is a lot of copy&pasting going on.)

Comment: I have posted an answer for you.  Your app clearly has some major technical debt, and the fact that you've gotten as far along as you have keeping the app as procedural as possible is absolutely frightening to me and I don't have long term hopes for the maintainability of your app.  If the app proves successful and requires long term support, it will also eventually require an absolute rewrite.  The sooner you start addressing technical debt, the better.  You might be able to get it straightened out to prevent the rewrite, but you need to start now and not later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little OOP can go a long way here.

First, let's make some base view controllers:

```
class GrayStatusBarViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // set up the appearance
    }
}

class BlackStatusBarViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // set up the appearance
    }
}
```

Now, we can make one of these for every appearance we want, and we can move any shared behavior into these *base classes* we want.  It probably makes sense for your app to have a `BaseViewController` which the two classes I just posted inherit from (rather than inheriting from `UIViewController` directly).

Then, all you have to do is make your pile of view controllers inherit from the correct controller based on theme.

```
class DeleteMatchViewController: GrayStatusBarViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated) // <-- this is super important

        // the rest of the view will appear code for this VC
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can encapsulate the appearance logic in methods in a class like I previously mentioned, the `BaseViewContoller`, something like this:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    func setUpGrayStatusBar() {
        // write that logic
    }

    func setUpBlackStatusBar() {
        // write that logic
    }

    // etc, as many of these as you want
}
```

And now, you inherit from this class and call the appropriate method:

```
class DeleteMatchViewController: BaseViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        setUpGrayStatusBar()
    }
}
```

---

When it comes to the run time performance of your application, neither of these solutions is any different from simply copy & pasting the same code into all of your individual view controllers.  Just because you didn't paste it in more than one place doesn't mean it doesn't run more than once.